# POO[python] - Función super() - ¿Cómo la implemento cuando tengo atributos privados?

Tags: python, poo, herencia

Muy buenas noches. Estoy teniendo problemas con el siguiente código:

```
class Cuenta:
    def __init__(self, titular = "", cantidad = ""):
        self.__titular = titular
        self.__cantidad = cantidad
    
    @property
    def titular(self):
        print(f"Titular:{self.__titular}")
    
    @titular.setter
    def titular(self,nuevoTitular):
        self.__titular = nuevoTitular
        print(f"El nuevo titular es: {self.__titular}")
    
    @property
    def cantidad(self):
        print(f"cantidad: {self.__cantidad}")
    
    def mostrar(self):
        print(f"Titular:\t\t {self.__titular}\n" \
              f"Cantidad:\t\t {self.__cantidad}\n")
    
    def ingresar(self,monto):
        if monto >= 0:
            self.__cantidad = self.__cantidad + monto
            print(f"Monto ingresado:\t {monto}\n" \
                  f"Saldo cuenta:\t\t {self.__cantidad}")
    
    def retirar(self,monto):
        self.__cantidad = self.__cantidad - monto
        print(f"Monto retirado:\t\t {monto}\n" \
              f"Saldo cuenta:\t\t {self.__cantidad}")


class cuentaJoven(Cuenta):
    def __init(self,titular = "",cantidad = "",bonificacion = 0):
        super().__init__(titular,cantidad)
        self.__bonificacion = bonificacion
    
    @property
    def bonificacion(self):
        print(f"Bonificacion: {self.__bonificacion}")

cuentaJ = cuentaJoven("gero",3000,0.3)
cuentaJ.bonificacion
```

Con la clase "Cuenta" no tengo ningún problema. El problema empieza cuando quiero heredarla a la clase "cuentaJoven". Si ejecuto ese código tal cual como aparece ahí me salta este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, si ejecuto el mismo código pero sin ingresar ningún parámetro me salta este otro error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así que eso, resumiendo, mi pregunta es... ¿Dónde la estoy cagando?... Espero haya algún alma caritativa que pueda ayudarme jajaja... De antemano muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la clase `cuentaJoven` estas poniendo

```
def __init(self,titular = "",cantidad = "",bonificacion = 0):
```

en lugar de

```
def __init__(self, titular="", cantidad="", bonificacion=0):
```

Respecto a la función `super()`, ésta sirve para invocar y conservar un método o atributo de la clase Padre.
La estas usando como es debido.

Comment: Era eso!!!!! pero que burro!!! jajajaja muchas gracias!!